# How to return a numpy array with values derived from the source array of max values of different arrays of same shape

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm have trouble writing this question out so maybe best just to illustrate. In short I have two sets of three arrays of the same shape. Using the first set, for each element, I would like to find which array has the max value in that position and return the value from the second set. While the example has each 3 x 3 shaped array as a different object they could just as easily be a (3 ,3 ,3).

The set to find the max value:

```
import numpy as np
A1 = np.array([[13, 16, 17], [32, 16, 11], [46, 30, 14]], dtype='uint8')
B1 = np.array([[31, 46, 41], [19, 29, 45], [36, 30, 46]], dtype='uint8')
C1 = np.array([[36, 35, 26], [19, 40, 24], [5, 20, 46]], dtype='uint8')
```

The set to use as the return value:

```
A2 = np.array([[1, 1, 4], [3, 1, 4], [1, 3, 2]], dtype='uint8')
B2 = np.array([[2, 3, 1], [4, 4, 2], [1, 1, 3]], dtype='uint8')
C2 = np.array([[3, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [2, 4, 4]], dtype='uint8')
```

If it's a two step solution the first would return an array like:

```
mx1
array([['C', 'B', 'B'],
       ['A', 'C', 'B'],
       ['A', 'A', 'B']], dtype='<U1')
```

Then the desired output is:

```
out1
array([[3, 3, 1],
       [3, 2, 2],
       [1, 3, 3]])
```

Note that in the event of a tie for max value(the last two elements) the value from the first encountered array is the accepted value.

I thought this would be a simple task using some np.max and np.where type magic but I can't seem to wrap my head around this problem correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

A1 = np.array([[13, 16, 17], [32, 16, 11], [46, 30, 14]], dtype='uint8')
B1 = np.array([[31, 46, 41], [19, 29, 45], [36, 30, 46]], dtype='uint8')
C1 = np.array([[36, 35, 26], [19, 40, 24], [5, 20, 46]], dtype='uint8') 

A2 = np.array([[1, 1, 4], [3, 1, 4], [1, 3, 2]], dtype='uint8')
B2 = np.array([[2, 3, 1], [4, 4, 2], [1, 1, 3]], dtype='uint8')
C2 = np.array([[3, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [2, 4, 4]], dtype='uint8')

D=np.array([A1,B1,C1])
F=np.array([A2,B2,C2])

amax=np.argmax(D,axis=0)
# array( [[2, 1, 1],
#         [0, 2, 1],
#         [0, 0, 1]] )

#There should be a better way to do this.
idx=np.array([ (y,x[0],x[1]) for x,y in np.ndenumerate(amax)])
# array([[2, 0, 0],
#        [1, 0, 1],
#        [1, 0, 2],
#        [0, 1, 0],
#        [2, 1, 1],
#        [1, 1, 2],
#        [0, 2, 0],
#        [0, 2, 1],
#        [1, 2, 2]] )

flat_answer=F[(idx[:,0],idx[:,1 ],idx[:,2])]
# array( [3, 3, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3] )

answer = np.reshape(flat_answer,np.shape(amax)))
# array( [[3, 3, 1],
#         [3, 2, 2],
#         [1, 3, 3]] )
```

The trick is to make a 3D array, form `A1`, `A2`, `A3`. then use [`argmax()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) to get the proper index.

I'm sure there is a "smart" numpy indexing way to reduce the dimension of F based on `argmax()` result. But my work around was to use [`ndenumerate()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndenumerate.html) and list comprehension to build a flattened array with the correct values via [multidimensional indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#indexing-multi-dimensional-arrays), then reshape it to `(3,3)` again.

---

Edit, better explanation:

`ndenumerate()` returns a generator of tuples with the coordinate and value for each position in the array, ie. for the array

```
[ [ 1, 2 ],
  [ 3, 4 ] ]
```

It will return the tuples:

```
( ( 0, 0 ), 1 )
( ( 0, 1 ), 2 )
( ( 1, 0 ), 3 )
( ( 1, 1 ), 4 )
```

But the values of `amax` are already coordinates in the 3rd dimension of `D` and `F`, so we concatenate the outputs of `ndenumerate(amax)` to build a coordinates of `F`

```
ndenumerate        coordinate
((x1, x2 ), v ) -> (v, x1, x2)
```

The last 2 lines of code, use the coordinates to project the answers from the 3x3x3 array `F` to a 3x3 `answer` using numpy indexing rules.

It's equivalent to doing the following mapping:

```
clearer_answer = np.zeros(np.shape(amax))
for x,y in np.ndenumerate(amax):
    clearer_answer[x] = F[(y,x[0],x[1])]
```

Comment: Thanks Xvan, I kept coming across the argmax() function but didn't realize how it works. I'm sure there is indeed a "smart" numpy answer that maybe someone else can offer. Could you explain what the idx array is? I can't quite wrap my head around it.